# Video RTC with src not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, video, webrtc, twilio

I'm setting up Twilio Video using their javascript API. My issue is that when I attach a participants video stream to a div, Twilio adds the proper video tag to the DOM, however I'm unable to see the participants' video. Here is a script I mocked to isolate the issue:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/v1/twilio-video.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="local"><video height=300 width=300></video></div>
  <div id="remote"></div>
  <script>
    var Video = Twilio.Video;
    var localMedia = new Video.LocalMedia();
    var user_uuid = scramble();
    var localVideo = document.querySelector("#local video");

    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia || navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia;

    navigator.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}, function(stream){
      localVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
      localMedia.addStream(stream);

      $.get("/api/match",
        {
          user_uuid: user_uuid
        }
      ).done(function(body){
        if(body.status_url){
          getParticipants(body.status_url, Video, localMedia, function(room){
            room.participants.forEach(function(participant){
              participant.media.attach("#remote");
            });

            room.once('participantConnected', function(participant){
              participant.media.attach("#remote");
            });
          });
        }
      });
    }, function(e){console.log(e)});

    function scramble(){
      function s4() {
        return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
          .toString(16)
          .substring(1);
      }
      return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
        s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
    }
    function getParticipants(status_url, Video, localMedia, cb){
      $.get(status_url).then(function(res){
        if (res.room && res.token){
          var room = res.room;
          var token = res.token;
          var client = new Video.Client(token);

          client.connect({
            to: room,
            localMedia: localMedia
          }).then(function(room){
            cb(room);
          }, function(error) {
            console.error('Failed to connect to the Room', error);
          });
        } else {
          setTimeout(function(){
            getParticipants(status_url, Video, localMedia, cb);
          }, 3000);
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

For context, I'm pinging a server until I match with another person to join the video conference. As soon as they do join, Twilio properly adds a new video tag along with a src BLOB to the DOM. The issue is that although the tag is added, no video is visible on the screen.

Has anyone seen something like this? Where a `<video>` tag is is visible in the DOM but you can't see any videos on the screen?

Comment: It seems that you're doing the right things, if it's still not working I recommend sending this detail to help@twilio.com and they can pass it on to the right team.

Comment: Hey bumpkin - did you ever get this working?  If so, would you be willing to share your code? I have things working as far as getting a token from my PHP server and connecting to a room but I can't see anything on the DOM what-so-ever...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the LocalParticipant class for the local user

```
var localMediaContainer = document.getElementById('local-video');

var videoElement;

const localParticipant = room.localParticipant; 

room.localParticipant.tracks.forEach(track => {       
    videoElement = track.attach();
    localMediaContainer.appendChild(videoElement);
});
console.log('Connected to the Room as LocalParticipant: ', localParticipant.identity);
```